# SQL QUERY to get Count of particular column between two Range of Dates

Tags: sql

Here I have a doubt regarding sql query.

In this scenario I have a table called tblcrime : where we will get the sum(crime) here I track MainID and sum(crime) query will be like this :

```
 SELECT sum(o.crimeID) as crimeNumber,u.UserID
    from tblcrime o
    inner join tblSubContractor ts on
    o.MainID=ts.SubContractorID
```

from here I will chk the `tblUSER` with these `subcontractorID` :

```
 inner join tblUser u on
    u.SubContractorID=ts.SubContractorID
```

and my doubt is that up to here I will get the total sum of crime and appropriate userid., for e.g.

```
UserID : 520 Totalcrime:6000
```

but there is another table called `tblAudit` where we will get logondate and userid, which is tracking here.. so I want to display crime based on userlogin(userid) ...since last login. So that when user login it shows in a jquery notification that "60 crimes has been done since last login".

I want help in query format.

Comment: Can you show us a bit more about the table structure? ie. Does table Crime or tblSubContractor have any datetime column that can be used etc.

Comment: Here tblAudit have logon date coloumn traking user by userid which is the primary key of tblUSER and tblcrime has 'crimedate' coloumn where it traks the crime done date.

Comment: Is this query user specific? ie. are you passing in the UserID as a parameter?

Comment: ya userid here is a parameter which is passed from UI level

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I understand your question right, but may this be, what you are looking for?

```
SELECT sum(o.crimeID) as crimeNumber,u.UserID
from tblcrime o
inner join tblSubContractor ts on o.MainID=ts.SubContractorID
inner join tblUser u on u.SubContractorID=ts.SubContractorID
where 
u.UserID = theOneYouAreLookingFor
AND crimedate >= lastLogOn
GROUP BY u.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I suspect that the call to the `SUM` function should really be to `COUNT`. The former adds the values of the specified column together, whereas the latter gives you a row count.

Secondly, does your `tblcrime` table store the date that crimes are added? I'll assume it does, let's call the column `DateAdded`. The following query should work:

```
SELECT      COUNT(o.crimeID) AS crimeNumber,
            u.UserID
FROM        tblcrime o
INNER JOIN  tblSubContractor ts on o.MainID = ts.SubContractorID 
INNER JOIN  tblUser u on u.SubContractorID = ts.SubContractorID
INNER JOIN  tblAudit a on a.userid = u.UserID
WHERE       a.logondate < o.DateAdded
GROUP BY    u.UserID
```

Comment: Ya but here logondate is on another table called tblAudit and instead of dateadded ter is another coloumn called crimedate where it traks the date which crimedone but it is in tblcrime.So here frm tblcrime i can only get count(crime) from tblcrime.but the userlogon details i want to track from tblaudit

Comment: Could you update the question to include your schema? It's near impossible to answer your question correctly without it.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the max auditdate for that user:

```
SELECT sum(o.crimeID) as crimeNumber,u.UserID
    from tblcrime o
    inner join tblSubContractor ts on
    o.MainID=ts.SubContractorID
inner join tblUser u on
    u.SubContractorID=ts.SubContractorID
where o.crimeDate >= (select max(auditdate) from tblAudit where UserID = @UserID)
```